# Copy database manually from one neo4j server to another neo4j server without migration using neo4j-shell

Tags: database, neo4j, data-migration

How to manually copy database(collection of nodes and relationships) from one neo4j database server to another neo4j database server.

In general, we can use neo4j-shell to export and import data(migration) between neo4j servers. This will take a lot of time, In mysql we can just copy the data folder to achieve this, is there a way to do this.

My requirement was i have a huge collection of nodes and relationships in my local neo4j server, i wanted to add it to docker-neo4j containers where ever i run.

Comment: Have you tried just copying your neo4j data folder?

Comment: @DavidMakogon i tried, the server will not start once we replace the graph.db folder.

Comment: And are you using the same Neo4J version in both places?

Comment: Local machine has 3.1.4 and server has 3.2.0

Answer (score 1):

copying the data folder does not work because the minor version numbers are different.
Try to see if there is something about data migration to 3.2 on the neo4j website.

Else export to csv then import ?

Answer (score 1):

Using the same versions, i could able to physically copy the database folders/files from one db instance to another db instance and see the data reflected.